# How to atribute dates to textbuttons in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

So, i'm building this app to make reservations on a restaurant menu, but to make the reservation, i need to create a new objetc that register the day of the reservation. I have a listview filtered by dayofweek and category, but i need that each button in the code below gets the next day as value. Example: today is thursday 08-04, so the "thursday" button gets 08-04 as value, friday button gets 08-05 as value, and the sequence continues.

```
// ignore_for_file: iterable_contains_unrelated_type

import 'package:apetit_project/data/dummy_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../components/meal_item.dart';
import '../../models/meal.dart';
import '../../models/week_button_gastronomy.dart';

class GastronomyOptionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Meal> meals;

  const GastronomyOptionScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.meals,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GastronomyOptionScreen> createState() => _GastronomyOptionScreenState();
}

class _GastronomyOptionScreenState extends State<GastronomyOptionScreen> {
  var _idDiaSem = 'seg';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dayOfWeekMeals = DUMMY_MEALS
        .where((meal) =>
            meal.idDiaSem.any((idDiaSem) => idDiaSem == _idDiaSem) &&
            meal.idCategory.any((idCategory) => idCategory == 'ga'))
        .toList();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: dayOfWeekMeals.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  elevation: 0,
                  margin: (index == dayOfWeekMeals.length - 1)
                      ? const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, left: 20, right: 20)
                      : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: (index == 0)
                        ? const BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                          )
                        : (index == dayOfWeekMeals.length - 1)
                            ? const BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
                              )
                            : BorderRadius.circular(0),
                    child: MealItem(dayOfWeekMeals[index]),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              WeekButton(
                'Segunda',
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _idDiaSem = 'seg'),
                selected: _idDiaSem == 'seg',
              ),
              WeekButton(
                'Terça',
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _idDiaSem = 'ter'),
                selected: _idDiaSem == 'ter',
              ),
              WeekButton(
                'Quarta',
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _idDiaSem = 'qua'),
                selected: _idDiaSem == 'qua',
              ),
              WeekButton(
                'Quinta',
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _idDiaSem = 'qui'),
                selected: _idDiaSem == 'qui',
              ),
              WeekButton(
                'Sexta',
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _idDiaSem = 'sex'),
                selected: _idDiaSem == 'sex',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can i make this _idDiaSem gets it`s corresponding date?

Comment: You can use [Intl Package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to Format your dateTime.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

> It's very easy using intl and DateTime. You can use this snippet for your reference.

**CODE**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  Duration dayOne;
  for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    dayOne = Duration(days: index);
    print(
      DateFormat('MM-dd')
      .format(
        DateTime.now().add(dayOne)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
08-04
08-05
08-06
08-07
08-08
```